# How do I add Unbound Column in a Continuous Form while allowing each row in the unbound column to be a unique user input

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula, ms-access-forms

I have an Excel table with Planned production information. I have an Access DB where I want to store this planned production information as well as Actual production information. I am using an Access form to allow users to log their actual production information according to the planned information. Using a continuous form I can pull all my planned information by having the Excel spreadsheet as a linked table. The problem is when I add an unbound column to this table for users to enter their Actual production information, all the row values for the new column is the same. [Continuous Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS5by.png)

I tried looking for control properties and using VBA code but I could not achieve the result I am looking for.

Comment: You cannot. Continuous forms require their columns to be bound to a backend field in order to be able to populate each row separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

1. get rid of Excel component and go all-Access instead of trying to make Excel work like a db
2. link to Excel so it can be edited, however, I doubt this would work nicely in a multi-user environment

A query object can establish direct link to Excel worksheet and allow edits and adding rows, but not delete rows. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sheet1$] IN 'C:\folderpath\filename.xlsx'[Excel 12.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=0;ACCDB=Yes];
```

IMEX=0 allows edit
Anything else would be ready only. External Data wizard will usually assign 2 for Excel link.

3. complicated VBA code manipulating Excel file to write data, again, probably won't work nicely in a multi-user environment